# Page_load time out is not working

Tags: watir

I am having this error after 60 secs of time since pages hasn't completed it's loading in 60 secs

Code I executed

```
b.element(:id,'Finish').click
```

Following error was thrown after 60 secs

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in `readuntil'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1437:in `block in transport_request'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `transport_request'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1400:in `block in request'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
 from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
```

So I have included this in my program

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
b=Watir::Browser.new :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps,profile: "default", http_client: client
```

But still it's working,

And then I included this code

```
browser.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 180
```

NO matter whatever I do, it always fails after 60 secs, Why is it so?

I have placed this question in watir-general, but no answer so far.

Comment: You dont want to add an additional `sleep()` command? 30-60secs is the default timeout set. Unless you are using `element_exists?` in your code, why not use a page wait seperately?

Comment: @Mrityunjeyan hi what does page wait has to anything here? You can't even use sleep statement here because it throws the error.